# Beryllium Release Unable to login on Web Interface (http://10.10.10.2:8181/index.html)

Tags: opendaylight

I have installed the Beryllium release with Mininet on the side and was able to have everything running however I can't login. I installed the following features:

```
sudo ./odl-controller/bin/client -u karaf -h localhost -r 7 "feature:install odl-dlux-all"
sudo ./odl-controller/bin/client -u karaf -h localhost -r 7 "feature:install odl-restconf-all"
sudo ./odl-controller/bin/client -u karaf -h localhost -r 7 "feature:install odl-openflowplugin-all"
sudo ./odl-controller/bin/client -u karaf -h localhost -r 7 "feature:install odl-l2switch-all"
sudo ./odl-controller/bin/client -u karaf -h localhost -r 7 "feature:install odl-mdsal-all"
sudo ./odl-controller/bin/client -u karaf -h localhost -r 7 "feature:install odl-yangtools-common"
```

When I try to access the open day light interface on http://10.10.10.2:8181/index.html#/login I can see the form, but using admin/admin says "Unable to login".

I'm using MacOSX and the version of ODL is 0.4.0-Beryllium. Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ILX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7fAD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beryllium is staggeringly old by ODL standards. It hasn't been supported upstream for many years. Please use a recent version of ODL.

https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/downloads.html

Comment: And once you start using a recent version, you'll notice that DLUX has been removed. There are many other questions about it here on SO, but tl;dr most actual devs didn't use it and no one stepped up to maintain it, despite many calls for help from upstream. Recommendation is to just not use DLUX, use REST API.

Comment: Thank you, @dfarrell07. I was using it on a university course for learning purposes and solved the issue by resetting the ODL database.